# I'd like to use the docker-py fake_api_client.py, but having trouble importing it

Tags: python, docker, import, modulenotfounderror

Beginner question:

I want to use this in my test file: https://github.com/docker/docker-py/blob/master/tests/unit/fake_api_client.py

I'm trying to import like this:

```
from docker.tests.unit import fake_api_client
```

but getting this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_something.py", line 2, in <module>
    from docker.tests.unit import fake_api_client
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'docker.tests'
```

Comment: The tests aren't part of the installed module; they're only available in the source package.

Comment: Thank you! Just curious - how do I tell which parts are included in the installed module?

Comment: In this case, you can look at the [`setup.py` file](https://github.com/docker/docker-py/blob/master/setup.py#L60), which says `packages=find_packages(exclude=["tests.*", "tests"]),`, which means "include in the package bundle any discovered Python packages other than the `tests` directory". More generally, it is very common for tests to be included in a top-level `tests` directory that will be excluded from the installed package.